# How to contain position absolute div?

Tags: html, css

I have this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/45atnh0u/) and this is the illustration below

[image]

what I need to achieve is to make the black container dynamically expand base on the item inside (the items are A, B, C) the output must be

[image]

without setting the height statically

my html is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="itemA">A</div>
    <div class="itemB">B</div>
    <div class="itemC">C</div>
<div>
```

my css is

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    min-height:300px;
    background-color:black
}
.itemA{
    position:absolute;
    top:260px;
    background-color:red;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
.itemB{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    right:90px;
    background-color:green;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
.itemC{
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    right:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: You need Js for that

Comment: As far as I know this cannot be done via CSS, as the children are absolute positioned there are in a sense not apart of the layout anymore. You could do this with Javascript by finding the furthest child down and setting the parent height to it.

Comment: could you help me how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script. First compute the max height then set the height of the container

```js
$(function(){
  var y = 0;
  $('.container .item').each(function(){
    y = Math.max(y, $(this).height() + $(this).position().top);
  });

  $('.container').css('height', y);
});
```

```css
.container{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    min-height:200px;
    background-color:black
}
.itemA{
    position:absolute;
    top:260px;
    background-color:red;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
.itemB{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    right:90px;
    background-color:green;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
.itemC{
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    right:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="itemA item">A</div>
    <div class="itemB item">B</div>
    <div class="itemC item">C</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to using jQuery so here it is, "borrowed" [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076231/how-to-get-height-of-the-highest-children-element-in-javascript-jquery) answer's code as its pretty much what we need. Just made some small changes.

So we look at the parents children `div` and get the farthest child position, add that child's height and then set the parents height to that. Boom, done.

```js
var t = 0;
$(".container div").each(function() {

  var position = $(this).position();
  if (position.top > t) {

    // Get the position and the height so we can set the parent height
    t = position.top + $(this).height();
    $('.container').height(t);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: black
}
.itemA {
  position: absolute;
  top: 260px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.itemB {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 90px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.itemC {
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  right: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="itemA">A</div>
  <div class="itemB">B</div>
  <div class="itemC">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In js you can have the position of each absolute-positionned elements. I wrote you a script that find the biggest value horizontaly and verticaly and apply this width and height to the container : http://jsfiddle.net/45atnh0u/7/
Its basically use `$(this).offset().left` and `$(this).offset().top`

But be carrefull with the right and bottom values.

Answer (score 0):

The closest is to give the container overflow: hidden , then move your elements left right top bottom in the dimensions of your container . If the `container has width 200px` you move element `left 200px - element width` and it shall remain in your container.

Updated fiddle:

```
.container{
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    min-height:200px;
    background-color:black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.itemA{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 170px;
    background-color:red;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
.itemB{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    right:90px;
    background-color:green;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
.itemC{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:30px;
    background-color:blue;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45atnh0u/8/

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned above JS might be a better fit, but I thought a quicker way with just `CSS` might also appeal.

The idea is for the `container` to take the height of the `body`.

Add

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and change your `container` height to

```
min-height:100%;
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45atnh0u/2/).

Hope it helps you.