# Dynamically add Component in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, components, angular-services, viewchild

How can I add component dynamically?

**toolbar.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  template: '<button>Add Text component</button>'
})
export class ToolbarComponent {
   constructor() { }
}
```

**section.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'div[app-type=section]',
   template: ''
})
export class SectionComponent {
   constructor() { }
}
```

**text.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-text',
   template: '<p>This is dynamically component</p>'
})
export class TextComponent {
   constructor() { }
}
```

**view.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-view',
   template: `<div class="container">
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
<div app-type="section" id="SECTION1" class="active"></div>
<div app-type="section" id="SECTION2"></div>
</div>`
})
export class SectionComponent {}
```

when I click to ToolBarComponent, I want to add TextComponent to SectionComponent which have "active" class.

Comment: Create a service with Subject(or BehaviourSubject) in it, in ToolbarComponent make Observable from click event, subscribe and `next` to that Subject from service. In that place where class `active` is added, `next` to other Subject in service (just now value of `next` is a reference to that element/component), so you wont need to query DOM. In ViewComponent dynamicly create component with `componentFactoryResolver`. Subscribe to both subjects and append component via `ng-template` and directive added to it. You probably can create `ng-template somedirectiveRef` dynamicly, and not in every HTML

Comment: Can you help me with a full  answer? Plz. Actually class "active" is not necessary, exactly I want to add the component to the section that is most visible on the screen. :D - like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360676/get-the-element-which-is-the-most-visible-on-the-screen

Comment: Please show your updated code then. If dynamic placeholder not needed - just hardocde in HTML - `<div app-type="section" id="SECTION1" class="active"> <ng-template myDirectiveThatReferencesTemplateComponentForInsertion></ng-template></div>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expose `viewContainerRef` on **section.component.ts**:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'div[app-type=section]',
   template: ''
})
export class SectionComponent {
  @Input() active: boolean;

   constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Add an output to **toolbar.component.ts**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  template: '<button (click)="addComponentClick.emit()">Add Text component</button>'
})
export class ToolbarComponent {
  @Output() addComponentClick = new EventEmitter();
   constructor() { }
}
```

In **view.component.ts** create a `ComponentFactory` for TextComponents to add them dynamically to **active** SectionComponents:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentFactory, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TextComponent } from './text.component';
import { SectionComponent } from './section.component';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-view',
   template: `<div class="container">
<app-toolbar (addComponentClick)="onAddComponentClick()"></app-toolbar>
<div app-type="section" id="SECTION1" [active]="true"></div>
<div app-type="section" id="SECTION2"></div>
</div>`
})
export class ViewComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChildren(SectionComponent) sections: QueryList<SectionComponent>;
  activeSections: SectionComponent[];
  textComponentFactory: ComponentFactory<TextComponent>;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.textComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TextComponent);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.activeSections = this.sections.reduce((result, section, index) => {
      if(section.active) {
        result.push(section);
      }
      return result;
    }, []);
  }

   onAddComponentClick() {
    this.activeSections.forEach((section) => {
      section.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.textComponentFactory);
    });
   }
}
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-dynamic-component-to-child)

Comment: How I will access all TextComponent "__id" variables?https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-dynamic-component-to-child-injywm?file=app%2Ftext.component.ts Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would do it using ngFor
**view.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-view',
   template: `
     <div class="container">
       <app-toolbar (addEvent)="addEvent($event)"></app-toolbar>
       <div app-type="section" id="SECTION1" class="active">
          <app-text *ngFor="let appText in textArray"></app-text>
       </div>
       <div app-type="section" id="SECTION2"></div>
     </div>
   `
})
export class SectionComponent {
   public textArray: string[] = [];
   public addEvent(event: string) : void {
      textArray.push(event);
   }
   ....
}
```

**toolbar.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  template: '<button (click)="addNewText()">Add Text component</button>'
})
export class ToolbarComponent {
   @Output addEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
   constructor() { }
   addNewText(): void {
      this.addEvent.emit("");
   }
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thank for help, but I want to use component. "TextComponent" is just my example. I have many of the same components. Ex: "HeadingH1Component", "ListULComponent", "ImageImgComponent"...

Answer (score 2):

I have another way of doing it, please check for you case

```
html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="COMPONENT"></ng-container>

.ts
import { COMPONENT } from './..dir../component'
```

OR

```
html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="option.component"></ng-container>

.ts
import { COMPONENT } from './..dir../component'    
option = {
  component: COMPONENT
}
```

OR if it is Dynamic, add the component to [entryComponent](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components)

```
app.module.ts
import { COMPONENT } from './..dir../component'
@NgModule({
   declarations: [COMPONENT],
   /.
   ..
   ..
  ./
  entryComponents: [COMPONENT]
});    

html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="option.component"></ng-container>

.ts
/** The COMPONENT is not imported since it is added to entrycomponent**/
@Input() option;
```